# Is $\mathbb{E}(\exp(-\hat{\mu})) = \exp(-\mu)$, when $\mathbb{E}\hat{\mu}=\mu$?

Tags: survival, bias, unbiased-estimator

Say I have a biased estimator for $\xi$, say $\hat{\xi}$.

But what I know is $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\mu}) = \mu$(**unbiased**), and  $\xi = \exp(-\mu)$.

So I wish to do the following bypass.

> Is $\exp(-\hat{\mu})$ is still unbiased, when $\mathbb{E}\hat{\mu}=\mu$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't - when exponentiating, you need to take higher moments into account.

See, e.g., the [lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution):

$$E(\exp X)= \exp\big(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\big) $$

where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are the mean and variances of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample, but could you be more specific about "you need to take higher moments into account"?

Comment: He is referring to the fact that $e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6....$. In that form you can see that they're equal only if all higher moments $X^k$ are unbiased for $\mu^k$